# Trying to find out the name with least length of name

Tags: python, function

```
def my_function(*kids):
    for i in kids:
        a=min(len(kids[i]))
        print(f'The youngest child is {a}')

my_function("Emil", "Tobias", "Linus")
```

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: You mean ```for i in range(len(kids)):```? Because ```kids``` contain strings

Comment: `i` is each string in the list, not the indices.

Comment: Also, you likely don't want to be looping at all. If you're trying to find the shortest string, that would be simply `min(kids, key=len)`.

Comment: I am trying to print the name with least length using UDF.

Comment: If I am using a=min(len(i)). then I am getting error : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Carcigenicate comment:

```py
def my_function(*kids):
    a = min(kids, key=len)
    print(f'The youngest child is {a}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def f(*names):
    _lens = min(len(x) for x in names)
    return [nm for nm in names if len(nm) == _lens]

_test_names = ["cal", "barbs", "Jack", "Kevin", "Ox"]
f(*_test_names)
```

```
['Ox']
```

Answer (score 0):

When the loop was reaching `a=min(len(kids[i]))` it was throwing an error because, behind the scenes it was working as `emil[emil]` which was wrong.  We need to pass an int value when we do slicing. The code below is perfectly working logic for your problem. I created a new list outside the loop to avoid the clash and its sorted.

```py
def my_function(*kids):
    list1=[]
    for i in kids:
        list1.append(i)
    a=min(list1)
    print(f'The youngest child is {a}')
        
my_function("Emil", "Tobias", "Linus")
```